# Problems with accessing parameters of MediaFrameSourceGroup on HoloLens 2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I am currently working with MediaFrameSourceGroup and I have noticed two things today where I do not know how to fix them. I hope someone can help me or at least explain them to me.

1. while I am searching with `await MediaFrameSourceGroup.FindAllAsync()` for all possible `MediaFrameSourceGroups` I wanted to get `DisplayName` and other parameters. This works for all parameters except the `Id`.
   As soon as I try to access it, my debugger detaches itself with the code `'The program 'Unity' has exited with code 1 (0x1).'`.
2. Although I have activated the research mode and was able to see both depth sensor with the [SensorVisualization Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/HoloLens2ForCV/tree/main/Samples/SensorVisualization), the depth sensor is not listed.

Now I have a more general question/problem, which I would like to mention here to not open a new question. I hope this is ok.

3. When I have loaded the app on the HoloLens 2 and connected the debugger, I get the following error
   `System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'advapi32.dll': The specified module could not be found.` This is accessed in `WindowsMixedRealityDeviceManager.cs`

According to similar questions I found with Google, the problem should not occur in the Unity version (2018.4.22f1) I use. How can you fix such an error without ideally updating Unity. I must honestly admit that I'm afraid of updating Unity, because I think that after that the app won't work anymore or I'll get other errors on board.

Answer (score 0):

> while I am searching with await MediaFrameSourceGroup.FindAllAsync() for all possible MediaFrameSourceGroups I wanted to get DisplayName and other parameters. This works for all parameters except the Id. As soon as I try to access it, my debugger detaches itself with the code 'The program 'Unity' has exited with code 1 (0x1).'.

Where is the error message you got? In Unity Editor or Visual Studio? It seems like Unity crashed when you're debugging the app. Would you be able to copy a stack at the crash? Thanks.

> Although I have activated the research mode and was able to see both depth sensor with the SensorVisualization Sample, the depth sensor is not listed.

Just as the link referred to in your comment says, currently, the research mode API only supported invoking directly from C++. However, it should be possible to use the API from C# as well, but you would have to rebuild the entire set of convenience functions / wrappers in the HoloLensForCV project yourself.

> When I have loaded the app on the HoloLens 2 and connected the debugger, I get the following error System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'advapi32.dll': The specified module could not be found. This is accessed in WindowsMixedRealityDeviceManager.cs

It should be a Unity side issue, we recommend that you re-open the bug or submit a new feedback to the Unity product team. Besides, we always recommend the latest Unity LTS (Long Term Support) stream as the best version so that we can avoid some known issue, and the current recommendation is to use Unity 2019.4.11f1: https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/lts-releases